# How to join two array attributes if the second is != "" in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have an array with two elements below:

```
if params["location"]
      params["location"]["street"] =[
          params["location"].delete("address1"),
          params["location"].delete("address2")
      ].compact.join(", ")
      l = ::Location.create!(street: params["location"]["street"],
            city: params["location"]["city"], 
            state: params["location"]["state"],
            zip: params["location"]["postal"], 
            country: params["location"]["country"])
```

What I am trying to do is join the two together sperated by a ", " only if address2 is an empty string/nil.

**Example 1:**

address1 = "56 West Gay Street"

address2 = "Apt. 211"

Actual: "56 West Gay Street, Apt.211"
Expected: "56 West Gay Street, Apt.211"

**Example 2:**

address1 = "56 West Gay Street"

address2 = ""

Actual: "56 West Gay Street, "
Expected: "56 West Gay Street"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `params['location']['address2']` is not empty, but an empty string. You can use [`present?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) to select only strings that are not blank.

```
if params['location']
  street = [
    params['location'].delete('address1'),
    params['location'].delete('address2')
  ].select(&:present?).join(', ')

  l = ::Location.create!(params['location'].merge('street' => street))
end
```

Comment: This would work on Rails, but if the question is about ruby, we would have to either define a `present?` method or compare it to `""` or `nil`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `a` and `b` are your two string:

```
[a,b].select(&:present?).join(", ")
```

Comment: this gives me true, false i think i need `&:presence` like the answer below. Thank you for your help though

Comment: The important part is exactly the same? Depends how you set a and b. `select` will select all values from an enumerable for which the given condition is truthy. So an empty string or nil would be dropped.